# Can we get a feature to bookmark responses so I can find them again later?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I really, really wish there was a way for me, within my profile or whatever, to bookmark responses I want to read again  on the website.

I can't find a place to discuss this in the stackexchange group of sites, so I decided to ask here, even at the very possible risk of snotty comments and/or official censure, knowing I will be pointed in the right way eventually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press the Star below the voting on each question. It will be stored as your favorites. You can always remove it later.

Comment: sorry, where would I find my favorites listed?

Comment: click your username at the top of the page, then click favourites in the menu bar across the middle.

Answer (score 1):

Below each answer, there is a small grey button called "link". If you click it, you get a permalink for the answer. You can bookmark it using the default mechanism of your browser.

(I assume that this is what you mean by "bookmark responses", and not that you want the bookmark to appear on your stackexchange profile; Switz already explained how you can do this for a question, but you then have to scroll for a specific answer).

Comment: Thanks Switz and rumtscho, I will follow Switz' advice, bookmarking in the browser wouldn't be the same because I wanted the bookmarks available regardless of the machine I am using.