# Is it possible to bookmark help pages. ( OR somehow retain notes about them in my profile)

Tags: support

I am a newbie, and will probably remain an infrequent poster on this forum.
Sometimes I may wish to bookmark a help page. I am well aware of how to do this in my browsers, but can it be done within the site so it appears in my profile?

I do realise the ordinary forum questions are bookmarkable, as are the meta questions. [Can we get a feature to bookmark responses so I can find them again later?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1264/can-we-get-a-feature-to-bookmark-responses-so-i-can-find-them-again-later)  <== That naked html transforms in to a neat link. And the page is bookmarkable.

- If I am not finding this option because it does not exist has it been suggested or discussed somewhere?
- If it is not an existing function and would need adding then are there alternatives that exist or could more easily be used?

  - I am thinking for instance that Wikipedia lets you add additional pages to your User profile. You may then do whatever you wish within reason in that new space, for instance creating a new persistent sandbox, keeping your own additional notes, copy and work on a large edit.
- I also note we may [answer our own questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) I suppose a workaround would be that if I take a long time to find something and it is not bookmarkable I could post about it within the meta section and be able to folow or bookmark that post.

### Examples

If I need to look something up in the help area I realise I may go to the help centre and that that is searchable.https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help <== That naked html remains as is and is apparently not bookmarkable

- Help for [Advanced Search](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/searching)
- Editing Help for [Advanced Links](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/editing-help#advanced-links) including Title Attributes that show on mouseover.
- [Markup Help](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) <== Note this link is to an external site. I can not expect that to be bookmarked directly from that external site to my profile. It is useful comprehensive and itself written in markdown.

  - But it could be useful to bookmark the post or page within *seasoned advice* which is [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/editing-help#need-more-detail)

Comment: Hi, I was wondering about your use case. The examples you mention are both syntax references, and each of them is already linked from the place where you need that syntax, the search bar and the post textbox respectively. Do you also need a bookmarking feature for other pages such as https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers (to pick one at random)?

Comment: Yes that would be handy too.  The problem is I tend to have a poor memory and once clicking on help links can get lost. I can waste time looking for something then when I next return can not recall where I found the answer and so look again.

Answer (score 1):

You could save them in the "About me" section of your profile; I've seen [other users doing that too](https://data.stackexchange.com/cooking/query/1282522). That section supports the same Markdown as questions and answers.

It's true that pages like https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help won't automatically be transformed into a link with proper title, but you already seem to know how to make formatted links yourself in Markdown.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds like it is a reasonable workaround. And one I probably would not have thought about trying to do. I may ave worried it was misusing the forums facilities.